# Is it good practice to use a free website as a package

Tags: java, programming-practices, packages

Is it good practice to use a free website as package identifier if I do not have a real website? EG `com.weebly.vikarjramun.myapp.myactivity` Just wondering...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the point of Java's package naming convention?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/117030/what-is-the-point-of-javas-package-naming-convention)

Comment: The purpose of using a domain name is to have uniqueness.  Whether it's a free website or not is largely irrelevant.  Whether you own the domain or not is very relevant, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little background:

> Companies use their reversed Internet domain name to begin their
>   package names—for example, com.example.mypackage for a package named
>   mypackage created by a programmer at example.com.

The reason of that convention is to avoid colissions since, jar files are treated as folders. If someone in a project have two jars with the same package hierarchy there maybe colissions.

[This answer to a similar question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/304284/61852) offers good free, more ellegant alternatives using things that you control, like your GitHub repository or your StackExchange profile to give uniqueness to your package hierarchies if you don't own a domain.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not whether the site is free or not, but whether you control the domain or subdomain in question. If you don't control the domain name, there is a risk that you may lose it to somebody else, and if that somebody else is also a Java developer, you may end up with a package name collision. If you do own the domain name, it doesn't even need to be in use - as long as you own it, you can be pretty sure nobody else will use it as a namespace.

If the domain is a subdomain under a domain owned by someone else, you probably don't have any guarantee that you wont lose it, e.g. if the company closes shop and someone else buys the assets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Both you and Tulains Cordova answered my question, but as he gave some alternatives, I selected his answer